# Parsing a space delimited string in Swift

Tags: string, swift

I have a text file containing a series of string parameters in this format:

```
# name:test name visible:false ignore:false comment:this is a comment
```

The parameters can be in any order, they can have any name, including ones I don't know. I want to parse these out into a dictionary. Using conventional string handling I would do this:

1. look for the first colon in the string
2. look backward from that point for the first space, or start of string
3. the parameter name is between those two points
4. look *after* the colon for the next colon, or end of string
5. look backward from that point for the first space character
6. the parameter value is between those two points
7. remove all of that text from the string, and repeat

Under Swift all of this seems surprisingly difficult. A lot of that is due to an almost complete lack of documentation and examples from Apple. I know I can use `rangeOfString` to find a colon, but I am lost how to find the *next* colon or the *previous* space. Even then, using the information in the Ranges to clip out the various bits seems difficult as well. I've found some helper code, but it's all for Swift 1.0, and no longer works under Swift 2.

So, does anyone have a pointer to a good set of routines for doing this sort of thing, or suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: Why you use such an unusual and error-prone format for your data? It would be much better to use a standard format like JSON. To get this I think you can use NSStringScanner and NSRegularExpression

Comment: Also if someone makes a comment like: I like the following thing: Test. You would have an error in the parsing

Comment: Indeed, and if I had a time machine to go back to the early 1970s I'd unplug the CDC 6600 it was written on and tell them to use JSON instead of punch cards and tape files. What, you think I'm kidding?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format isn't one of the usual one used on IOS but it can be handled with a few transformations:

```
var dict:[String:String] = [:]

let line = "name:test name visible:false ignore:false comment:this is a comment"

// The process:
// - separate components on spaces
// - re-combine using \n before elements containing ":" and restoring spaces for others
// - separate into array of key:value (now separated by \n)
// - remove empty element before first key:value pair
// - separate each key:value into a two element array
// - assign values to keys in dictionary
//
line.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")               
    .reduce("", combine: { $0 + ($1.containsString(":") ? "\n" : " ") + $1 })
    .componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
    .filter({ $0 != "" })
    .map({ $0.componentsSeparatedByString(":") })
    .forEach({ dict[$0.first!] = $0.last })

//   dict will contain :
//
//   visible:false
//   comment:this is a comment
//   ignore:false
//   name:test name
```

Comment: That is, without doubt, the most amazing code I've ever seen. You have reduced a significant amount of truly nasty work with those &*^&%^ Ranges (come on, I can't even +1 the index?!) into a single line of code!